# Replace repetitive values in column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to add a column which has values not equal to column `N` after `N=31` has reached and then plot it like
`plt.plot(X[N==1],FT[N==1]), plt.plot(X[new_col==63],FT[new_col==63])`
The data is following

```
+-------+-----+----+-------+-------+
| X     |  N  | CN | Vdiff | FT    |
+-------+-----+----+-------+-------+ 
|   524 |   2 |  1 |   0.0 | 0.12. |
|   534 |   2 |  1 |   0.0 |0.134. |
|   525 |   2 |  1 |   0.0 |0.154. |
|     . |     |    |       |.      |
|     . |     |    |       |.      |
|  5976 |  31 | 14 |   0.0 |3.54.  |
|  5913 |  31 | 29 |   0.1 |3.98.  |
|  5923 |   0 | 29 |   0.0 |3.87.  |
|     . |     |    |       |.      |
|     . |     |    |       |.      |
| 33001 |   7 | 36 |   0.0 |7.36   |
| 33029 |   7 | 36 |   0.0 |8.99   |
| 33023 |   7 | 43 |   0.1 |12.45  |
| 33114 |   0 | 43 |   0.0 |14.33  |
+-------+-----+----+-------+-------+
```

The solution I want is

```
+-------+-----+----+-------+------+
| X     |  N  | CN | new_col | FT  |
+-------+-----+----+-------+------+ 
|   524 |   2 |  1 |   2 | 0.12. |
|   534 |   2 |  1 |   2 |0.134. |
|   525 |   2 |  1 |   2 |0.154. |
|     . |     |    |     |.      |
|     . |     |    |     |.      |
|  5976 |  31 | 14 |  31 |3.54.  |
|  5913 |  31 | 29 |  31 |3.98.  |
|  5923 |   0 | 29 |  32 |3.87.  |
|     . |     |    |     |.      |
|     . |     |    |     |.      |
| 33001 |   7 | 36 |  45 |7.36   |
| 33029 |   7 | 36 |  45 |8.99   |
| 33023 |   7 | 43 |  45 |12.45  |
| 33114 |   0 | 43 |  46 |14.33  |
+-------+-----+----+-------+-------+
```

Note that values in `new_col` should be also repetitive like values in `N` and should not change in every new row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this the ouput you need? We cannot simply `groupby` by `N` as it has repetitive, non-adjacent values, as we need to preserve the order. We count here the condition where `N` is changed compared to its own previous value.

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(
"""X|N|CN|Vdiff|FT
524|2|1|0.0|0.12
534|2|1|0.0|0.134
525|2|1|0.0|0.154
5976|31|14|0.0|3.54
5913|31|29|0.1|3.98
5923|0|29|0.0|3.87
33001|7|36|0.0|7.36
33029|7|36|0.0|8.99
33023|7|43|0.1|12.45
33114|0|43|0.0|14.33"""), sep="|")

# works in pandas 1.2
#>>> df["new_val"] = df.eval("C = N.shift().bfill() != N")["C"].astype(int).cumsum()

# works in older pandas
>>> df["new_val"] = (df.N.shift().bfill() != df.N).astype(int).cumsum()
>>> df
       X   N  CN  Vdiff      FT  new_val
0    524   2   1    0.0   0.120        0
1    534   2   1    0.0   0.134        0
2    525   2   1    0.0   0.154        0
3   5976  31  14    0.0   3.540        1
4   5913  31  29    0.1   3.980        1
5   5923   0  29    0.0   3.870        2
6  33001   7  36    0.0   7.360        3
7  33029   7  36    0.0   8.990        3
8  33023   7  43    0.1  12.450        3
9  33114   0  43    0.0  14.330        4
```

Comment: It is giving me error `unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'`

Comment: Then you need to provide data sample closer to real.

Comment: you can view the data file in csv format on this link https://pern-my.sharepoint.com/:x:/g/personal/shah_8113394_talmeez_pk/ESSZr23UOg5Np291ygC4TFsBQZuuxS-mJPY7wTCe6ERs0A?e=D9vRQD

Comment: @شاهنواز it is out of scope of this question already, but it works for me with your excel. Pandas version `1.2.4`.

Comment: I have pandas version 1.0.5

Comment: Code updated. Checked in pandas 0.24. Should work now.